# Google App Engine context.Context vs gorilla context

Tags: google-app-engine, go

In GAE Go, in order to log, we need to create a new context using `appengine.NewContext(r)` which returns `context.Context`.

How do I use this context to set/get variables at request scope? In Gorilla, [Context](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context) has a clean Set/Get functions on context which is what I want to use in my code. However I do not want to import 2 different context packages.

GAE logging forces you to use `context.Context`.

```
//handlerFunc

func MyFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    // I want to set request scoped variables in context and pass it to doSomething.
    doSomething(ctx,w,r);
}

func doSomething(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Debugf(ctx, "Beginning doSomething"); //requires context parameter
    // get the request scoped variables from context. How? Use Gorilla Context?
}
```

Comment: Create a custom handler type (with context as one of the params), and have your router or some middleware (first in the chain) call NewContext to initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    gorillacontext "github.com/gorilla/context"    
)
```

I know this isn't the answer you want, but there's no way around it since the '[context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context#Context)' package in the Go standard library (used by App Engine) doesn't provide the functionality you want as compared to Gorilla's '[context](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context)' package. If you want to use additional frameworks that define their own 'context' packages, you will need to use multiple imports.

There's a good point made about these two contexts on a [groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gorilla-web/DF9xYrGuHKg) in that possibly Gorilla's context is misnamed since they are both used for different purposes - "The App Engine one stores credentials to make RPC requests; the Gorilla one is just a container for request globals."